# Xcode 11 GM Seed 2 freezes while building workspace/project

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, ios13, xcode11

I have recently downloaded new `Xcode 11 GM Seed 2` so that i can update my project to support Dark mode. (I am already on MacOS Catalina latest beta version-19A558d).

I have my project(workspace with pods) working 100% fine with Xcode 10.2. When I have started building same project with newly installed `Xcode 11 GM Seed 2`, It randomly freeze while building with title `Building X of Y tasks`. It randomly stops building any file at anytime. As per my different observations, It stops building while it is building library from my Pods.

I have already tried cleaning, manually deleting derived data files. Also, i have tried by reinstalling Xcode. Also restarted Mac to give try. All trial get failed. If anyone faced same issue and know the solution, please post here.

Comment: This might sound weird (as always) but i had similar issue and it turns out it had something to do with disk space. Issue gone when I've freed around 10gb of disk space.

Comment: I have already 30 GB of free space

Comment: Another guess -- command line tools version in Xcode settings?

Comment: let me check that.. probably that might be issue

Comment: @inokey : just checked. Command line tools are also of Xcode 11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disable the Swift Optimizer for SwiftSoup:

[image]

Comment: I had to do this on my actual application target, due to extensions on the `Collection` protocol

Comment: I don't have swift soup in my Pods

Answer (score 0):

I were trying all day hard to solve this issue. Finally issue get resolved.

Actually i tried to build/compile the app via Terminal. Then i found that it got struck/freezed while compiling the files from installed 3rd party libraries from pods. The 3rd party library named `SwiftSoup` was making problem. Then i removed that pod, and commented out the code related to that. And tried compiling/building the app again. And It worked successfully this time.

**UPDATE:**
I followed @Paul's Answer, that works without removing pod, keeping same pod and code working. Just need to update settings as described by him. But make sure, that you need to change this setting every time you update your pods.

Comment: Other option is to turn off optimization in the SwiftSoup build target to work around the infinite loop bug in the Swift optimizer.

Comment: @PaulBeusterien : I am not sure about how to turn off the swift optimizer for given pod. Can you please give me detailed step about how to do that for given pod.

Comment: Added an answer with a screen shot demonstrating it.

Comment: Will surely apply this today once i get time.